# Redirect to a specified directory when type given URL for Azure Static Website

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I created an Azure Static Website which works based on the Azure Blob storage.
To simplify the problem lets say:

- the root directory contains two folders `foo` and `bar`.
- Inside the `foo` folder, there is another folder `neo`. Inside the `neo` folder, there is a file `baz.html`
- Inside the `bar` folder which is located in the root directory, there is only one file `aim.html`.

So to display the baz.html I need to type the following URL address in the web browser: 
`https://somename.z19.web.core.windows.net/foo/neo/baz.html`

To display the aim.html I need to type the
`https://somename.z19.web.core.windows.net/bar/aim.html`

The question is: is there any setting in Azure which lets me specify the URL e.g.

```
https://somename.z19.web.core.windows.net/abc/def/
```

and when someone hits this URL he will be automatically redirected to the `https://somename.z19.web.core.windows.net/foo/neo/baz.html` address?

Cheers

Comment: was the provided answer helpful for you ?

Comment: yes, sry for late update of the question. Ive added a comment under your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [Azure custom domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name) to configure specific URLs, you can also do the same using [CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain). If your customers have to click on a specific link and you want to point them out to that directory, DNS would be that best approach.

Comment: yep, I've learned how to managed URLs using the CDN. To do this, I had to create an Azure CDN and an endpoint under the CDN. Then there is a possibility to create own Redirect or URL Rewrite rules in the external platform called Verizon which is linked to the CDN.